# Can I Use Visual Studio to Create Android Applications in HTML5?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012

I would like to make use of Visual Studio's HTML5 intellisense. If I create an HTML app in Visual Studio, can I somehow embed it in an android browser app that directly opens up that HTML page? Can I make it as an APK?

Edit: Looking for Free solutions only that would give me out-of-the-box APK generation capabilities from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Why would you want to do that to begin with?

Comment: I have made my intention very clear. I would like to make use of Visual Studio's HTML5 (HTML and JavaSript and CSS3) intellisense - That's for choosing VS.

Comment: Before someone starts asking why HTML5 - That's because I am a client-based developer and I would like to capitalize my skills.

Comment: +1 Very clear question

Comment: I think my question is very clear and I got the answer I was looking for.  I am not sure why my quertion is shown as [On Hold]. If you think it is too broad and there are other solutions, please try to post a few of them so that I can try them out as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this.

http://blog.geekypedia.net/archive/2013/10/08/android-app-development-in-html5-using-visual-studio-2012-express.aspx

It will allow you to develop your HTML5 Apps in Visual Studio (even express editions) and directly build APK from there.

Comment: Does it only work in Express edition? I mean I would be glad because that's what I am using anyway.

Comment: It works with all editions of Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I am trying this solution right now! Will share my results in some time.

Comment: Yay! I am able to create APK for a sample page! Thank you :) This solution works absolutely fine!

Comment: APKs are getting installed in my device. Marking this as answer.

Comment: You can use http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/introduction/index is really good as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create HTML5 apps in Visual Studio. Then you can use PhoneGap to convert it into Android App

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you would like to add some more information for the OP to be easier to follow your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I would just build it the same way you would build any HTML5 website using Visual Studio. Then I would download PhoneGap http://phonegap.com. After you have downloaded phonegap you can navigate to your projects directory and build the App. Follow the following documetation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface to build the app.

There was a Visual Studio plugin for phonegap that would plug in to Visual Studio so you could just uss F5 to build the app and run it in an Emulator. I will check and see if I can find it